# Formik values empty

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have the following Formik form

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }}
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
    setSubmitting(true);
    fetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setSubmitting(false);
        if (!response.success) return showAlert();
        login(response.user);
        history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }}
>
  {({ isSubmitting }) => (
    <Form className={classes.form}>
      <TextField
        required
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        label="Email"
        name="email"
        autoFocus
      />
      <TextField
        required
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        name="password"
        label="Wachtwoord"
        type="password"
      />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.submit}
        disabled={isSubmitting}
      >
        Log in
      </Button>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Link href="/register" variant="body2">
            {'Nog geen account? Registreer nu!'}
          </Link>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

For some reason the values in the `onSubmit` are empty, how can I set it to the values inside the form? The only difference between this form and another one I got to work is that this one does not have a validation schema but I can not imagine that is required

Comment: please show what is in `TextField`

Comment: TextField is a component from React material ui https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/ I just enter regular text inside of them before submitting

Comment: Formik Fields supports onChange as default, but if you are using other components or default input tag, you must pass onChange and handleChanges for that

Comment: Thanks, adding handleChange worked

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [example in formik's docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#example).

`TextField` isn't connect to `Formik`. When the value of `TextField` changes, `Formik` don't change, you need `Field` (`import { Field } from 'formik'`) that will render `TextField`.

Example for `email`

```
<Field
    name="email"
    render={({ field /* _form */ }) => (
        <TextField 
            required
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
            label="Email"
            autoFocus            
            {...field} 
        />
    )}
/>
```

If you are using a external input, you should use this way.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to pass this**

```
onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
value={values.email}
```

to the **Textinput**, and for Password aswell.
Your **Textinput** doesn't track any changes or submission.

[Check here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field)